# Homestead + Symfony 2.7 Installation

Tags: php, apache, symfony, nginx, homestead

I'm having problems trying to install Symfony2 on the Laravel Homestead Vagrant box..

I repeatedly keep getting a 403 response when entering the URL.

I have this in my `Homestead.yaml` and have added `test.dev` to my hosts file.

```
    folders:
        - map: ~/code
          to: /home/vagrant/code

    sites:
        - map: test.dev
        to: /home/vagrant/code/symfony-test
        # Also tried /home/vagrant/code/symfony-test/web
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your variant:

        `# Also tried /home/vagrant/code/symfony-test/web`

is right. Just point in browser to http://test.dev/app.php because by default homestead looking for index.php or rename your app_dev.php to index.php!
If you need dev mode comment in app_dev.php lines 12-18

Answer (score 12):

For others looking into this, I believe there may be a better answer. I had trouble with getting Symfony 2 up and running with Homestead but found a few simple things in the process.

In my case, I took those errors as warnings of a deeper problem so I continued to look for the answer. I am using [Homestead on a per-project basis](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/homestead#per-project-installation), and Symfony was having some trouble with routing. In this case, the 403 error is indicative of permission denial - which would be mostly likely acquainted with the server trying to serve the wrong file. In Symfony installations running on Apache, this is usually resolved with the `.htaccess` file, but Homestead in Nginx and as such, obviously works differently.

First, Homestead comes with a Symfony provisioner baked into it which needs to run to set up Symfony's routing requirements. Enable it simply by adding this line under `sites` to make it looks like this (notice the `type` key):

```
sites:
    - map: symfony.dev
      to: "/home/vagrant/symfony/web"
      type: symfony
```

Then start and provision Vagrant: `vagrant up --provision`. Make sure to clear the cache, but otherwise, you should be up and running.

### Using App_Dev.php

**Note:** I recommend against renaming `app_dev.php` as that is not necessary.

To get the dev environment working for Symfony, I added my Homestead IP address to the security check in `app_dev.php` like this (roughly line 12 - notice the last line in the parenthesis starting with `&&`):

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])
    || isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])
    || !(in_array(@$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], array('127.0.0.1', 'fe80::1', '::1')) || php_sapi_name() === 'cli-server')
    && $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] != '192.168.10.24'
) {
    header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
    exit('You are not allowed to access this file. Check '.basename(__FILE__).' for more information.');
}
```

Now, if you'd like to set `/app_dev.php` as your default file, you can do this in one of two ways. Unfortunately, neither are permanent (please leave a comment if you know of a good way). You need to change the `app.php` to `app_dev.php` in your `/etc/nginx/sites-available/[site name]` config file.

```
location / {
    try_files \$uri \$uri/ /app.php?\$query_string;
}
```

You might want to add `app_dev.php` to this list as well (about line 7):

```
index index.html index.htm index.php app.php;
```

You can SSH into your server by running (you will likely need to use `sudo`):

- `vagrant ssh`
- `cd /etc/nginx/sites-available/[your site]` (where [your-site] is set under "`map`" above
- `service nginx restart`
- `service php5-fpm restart`

Or go to `/vendor/laravel/homestead/scripts/serve-symfony2.sh` and change the appropriate lines. Again, modifying files in your /vendor directory is **NOT** recommended as it likely will be overwritten. You decide if that is worthwhile to you.

Don't forget to review [Symfony's docs on server config](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/web_server_configuration.html).

Comment: Just adding a information in this helpful tutorial, I tried to restart the services without `sudo` and did not work, so, before trying to restart, access `sudo`.

Comment: I've installed today vagrant and homestead, just adding ``type: symfony`` worked like a charm. Under ``sites-available`` ``index`` was already configured with ``app_dev.php``. So when you access the website ip or hostname app_dev.php is called as index

Comment: Have used `type: symfony` for ages, but it was the `$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']` that did the trick. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 3):

I've created a symlink of app.php and it worked for me.

```
ln -s app.php index.php
```